# Cross origin with Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am trying to run a very simple Angular ui-router project and I am getting the well known error: `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource`.

The URLs are presented in the following way: `file:///C:/test/routing/testrouting.html#/route1`. I have ***nodeJs*** installed in my Windows 10 machine. In which format do I have to write the files and what do I have to do with nodeJS?

This is a piece of my code:

```
angular.module('routingExample')
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

      // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")

      $stateProvider
        .state('route1', {
            url: "/route1",
            abstract:true ,
            templateUrl: "route1.html"
        })
      ...
```

Comment: I think you should not serve your web page from the file system, but from a simple http server (try nodejs module called "http-server", it would do the job). That's were your cross-origin error comes from.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that you are opening your html page (application directly in the browser). In order to run the application and route properly, you need to have a web server running which hosts you application. Having NodeJS installed is not sufficient, you need to create a NodeJS application server which serves you angular application. Here is a good tutorial that can get you started: https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular

Comment: What exactly to do with http-server @Clement? Could you give me some more details?

Comment: Actually, you can use any http server. But if you want to use http-server :
npm install -g http-server /
go to the right folder /
http-server . /
and connect to your site hosted on your computer.

Comment: I have installed http-server and http://localhost:8080 works. However what else do I have to do as my files to be served from the http server? For the time being nothing has changed.

Comment: Use Webstorm. It creates a web server and will run your index.html on it.